# Edit ListBox on MainWindow from a class

Tags: c#, wpf, reference

I have a WPF application, i created a new class named `Agent`. On my WPF application window i have `ListBox`. I call `Agent` from the MainWIndow.xaml.cs .

Agent class runs a `FileSystemWatcher` and now when `OnChanged` event is raised i want to add the message to the `ListBox` that the event was raised.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window x:Class="MachineLogAgentGUI.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="411" Width="515">
<Grid Background="#0A000000">
    <Button Content="Run Agent" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="397,12,0,0" Name="runAgent" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Click="runAgent_Click" />
    <ListBox Margin="12,66,12,12" Name="messageBox" />
    <TextBox Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="observedDirectory" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" />
    <Button Content="Browse" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="271,12,0,0" Name="browse" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="browse_Click" />
    <CheckBox Content="Include Subfolders" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,44,0,0" Name="includeSubfolders" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</Grid>
```

In MainWindow.xaml.cs i have:

```
    Agent agent = null;

    private void runAgent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (agent == null || !agent._running)
        {
            agent = new Agent(@"W:\MindWare.SVN\CardMax2\trunk\ProcessEngine\TSPHelper.Producer\bin\Debug\GeneratedLogs");
            runAgent.Content = "Stop Agent";
        }
        else if (agent._running)
        {
            agent.StopAgent();
            runAgent.Content = "Run Agent";
        }
    }
```

And Agent class:

```
public class Agent
{
    private string Path { get; set; }
    public bool _running { get; set; }

    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

    [PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public Agent(string path)
    {
        Path = path;
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Filter = "*.txt";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        _running = true;
    }

    // Stop Agent
    public void StopAgent()
    {
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        _running = false;
    }

    // Define the event handlers.
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {        
        try
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            _running = false;

            // DO SOMETHING HERE
            // Add item to ListBox on MainWindow somehow
        }
        finally
        {
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _running = true;
        }
    }
```

How i could do that?

Comment: Want to give us what you have so far? I'm guessing most people won't feel like typing out the entire program for you, but we can help you fill in the blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean.

You could create a static MainWindow object in the Agent class:

```
public class Agent
{
public static MainWindow mainWindow;

....
}
```

Then inside the MainWindow.cs you can add your window to the variable

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Agent.mainWindow = this;
  ....
}
```

Now when ever you need to access this you can reference mainWindow:

```
public class Agent
{
public static MainWindow mainWindow;

public void AddToList(string value)
{
   mainWindow.listBox1.items.add(value);
}
```

Edit: Update for Threading error

Sounds like the FileSystemWatcher runs on a seperate thread to the UI. you can manage this by getting passing the work to the UI thread

```
// DO SOMETHING HERE
// Add item to ListBox on MainWindow somehow
if (!mainWindow.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
       mainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
           new Action(
              delegate()
              {
               //Code to make changes to the mainWindow if the thread does not have access:
                mainWindow.listBox1.Items.Add("hello");                                
              }));
    }
    else
    {
        //Access allowed make changes normally.
        mainWindow.listBox1.Items.Add("hello");
    }
```

Martyn

Comment: @hs2d I've added some more code above to allow you to change the listbox from a different thread.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not do that since model-classes should be independent from the view.

Other than that why not pass a reference to the constructor of the class or exposing the ListView field as a public or internal property?

---

To expose your ListBox create a property like this:

```
public ListBox MessageBox { get { return messageBox; } }
```

This should be in your MainWindow code behind, then you can access the ListBox on any instance of the window via `mainWindow.MessageBox`.

Comment: How to expose my ListBox as public?

Comment: You still need a reference to the window instance of course unless you work with static properties which i would not recommend. (There already is a property for the [MainWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.mainwindow.aspx) in the `App` class, just set it when you create the main window, then you can access the ListBox from everywhere via `(Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).MessageBox`)

Comment: Cant really do that allso. Getting error: 
`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

Comment: Have a look at the **[threading model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx)**, you need to use the Dispatcher for any calls to UIElements from different threads. (You should probably do this via [databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) though)